Ubuntu extending disk issue - Disk in unusable state
Trying to extend a LVM in my ubuntu VM but running into an issue that I haven't been able to resolve by searching this site.
When I run df -h I get the following output:
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              197M   21M  176M  11% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   12G   11G  234M  98% /
tmpfs                              983M     0  983M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  375M  1.5G  21% /boot
tmpfs                              197M  4.0K  197M   1% /run/user/1000

As you can see there's only 234M remaining on the /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv disk.
However when I run sudo pvresize -v /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv I get the following:
 Cannot use /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: device is not in a usable state
 0 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized

Like I said I searched around but haven't figured out anything that helps.


However when I run sudo pvresize -v /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv I get the following:

That's not strange. pvresize is for resizing Physical Volume.
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is a Logical Volume, and you should use lvresize to resize it.
LVM is structured in Volume Groups (VG), which is built up of Physical Volumes (PV). A VG can hold Logical Volumes. Thus, if you increase the size of the device holding the PG, you have to first resize the PG, then the LV.
In addition to resizing a PG, a VG can be resized by adding more PVs to it, so a VG can span multiple PV's.
You can use pvdisplay to show a list of PV's and their size, and lvdisplay to show a list of LV's and their size. Finally, vgdisplay will show VG's.
